# How to create a progress bar

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

On a button click, I want to display a  progress bar, When it completes 100% want to load something,For this stuff i want to use jQuery as well as css.
I need some help, how to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**jQuery UI library**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) makes it easy. The examples on that page show how to create a progress bar, and the "Methods" tab shows how to update the value.